# Unable to configure ssl on mariadb using certbot generated certificates and private key

Tags: ssl, openssl, mariadb, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using certbot to generate a certificate for mariadb server and client ,but it's not working.

```
sudo certbot certonly -d mariadbserver -d mariadbuser
```

This is the command that i've used to generate certificates using certbot, I've got 4 files for both mariadbserver and mariadbuser . `cert.pem,chain.pem,fullchain.pem,privkey.pem`.

For the above 8 files i've created one certificates folder in `/etc/my.cnf.d/certificates`,First i've copied server files to this folder and renamed it for better understanding similarly did the same thing to client files also. my folder looks like

```
client-cert.pem client-chain.pem client-fullchain.pem client-privkey.pem server-cert.pem server-chain.pem server-fullchain.pem server-privkey.pem
```

then i executed

```
sudo chown -R mysql. /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates
```

I have added below snippets in server configuration i.e `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mariadb]
ssl-ca= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-chain.pem
ssl-cert= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-cert.pem
ssl-key= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-privkey.pem

[client-mariadb]
ssl-ca= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/client-chain.pem
ssl-cert= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/client-cert.pem
ssl-key= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/client-privkey.pem
```

Then i've restarted mariadb server using `sudo service mariadb restart`.But after doing this when i login to mariadb, cipher is showing not in use.

I tried to combine cert as `cat server-cert.pem client-cert.pem > ca-cert.pem` and use it in `ssl-ca= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/ca-cert.pem` for both server and client CA. That's not working for me.

what should i do? am i doing anything wrong in the above steps.please help

Comment: Try to use fullchain instead of serverchain

Comment: Have you got any logs? Often you can find what's wrong in them.

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov, fullchain is also not working for me. i tried to combine chain.pem and cert.pem and use it as certificate but that one is also not working.

Comment: Hi @NikitaKipriyanov, i have included error log in the configuration, but no errors reported. i can able to login mariadb terminal. if i give `mariadb --help` in that it showing ssl -True, and i can see the path for all the 3 categories. but if i give `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'`  it is showing empty. and status also showing cipher not in use.